# Javafx with Spring's ApplicationEventPublisher

Tags: spring, events, javafx-8

I have an `JavaFX` application which uses `Spring Framework` for dependency injection. Everything is working fine.

The only problem is when i use `ApplicationEventPublisher` to publish events for other controllers to listen to.

## Scenario

On adding a new customer, the modal where customer details is captured publisher `AddCustomerEvent`, where `CustomersController` listens to the event and gets the newly added customer and add it to available list of customers.

## Problem

`EventListener` method gets the event and thus new customer, but is not added to customer list. Furthermore, when i 'hardcode' a new `Customer` to be added to the customer list binded to tableView, the `Customer` is not displayed in the tableView.

**Publisher:**
The following is the publisher controller. It publishes an event that contains the new `Customer` for other controllers to subscribe to.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class AddUpdateCustomerController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button btnSave;
    @FXML
    private Button btnCancel;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtFirstName;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtSecondName;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtPhone;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        btnSave.setOnAction(this::handleSaveCustomer);
    }    

    private void handleSaveCustomer(ActionEvent event){
        String firstName = txtFirstName.getText();
        String secondName = txtSecondName.getText();
        String phone = txtPhone.getText();

        Customer c = new Customer(1, firstName, secondName, phone);
        AddCustomerEvent addCustomerEvent = new AddCustomerEvent(c);
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(addCustomerEvent);
    }
}
```

**Subscriber:**
This bean listen to the event published by publisher(`AddUpdateCustomerController` class) in method `addCustomerEventListener(AddCustomerEvent addCustomerEvent)`

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class CustomersController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Customer> tblCustomers;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Customer, String> clmFirstName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Customer, String> clmSecondName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Customer, String> clmPhone;
    @FXML
    private Button addCustomer;

    private final ObservableList<Customer> customerList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final ListProperty<Customer> customerListProperty = new SimpleListProperty<>();

    @Autowired
    protected AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Autowired
    protected Stage primaryStage;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        clmFirstName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
        clmSecondName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("secondName"));
        clmPhone.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("phone"));
        customerListProperty.set(customerList);
        tblCustomers.itemsProperty().bind(customerListProperty);
        addCustomer.setOnAction(this::addCustomerActionEvent);

        customerList.add(new Customer(1, "Name 1", "Second 1", "001"));
        customerList.add(new Customer(2, "Name 2", "Second 2", "002"));
        customerList.add(new Customer(1, "Name 3", "Second 3", "003"));
        customerList.add(new Customer(1, "Name 4", "Second 4", "004"));

    }    

    private void addCustomerActionEvent(ActionEvent event){
        try {
            Parent loader
                    = SpringFXMLLoader.create()
                            .applicationContext(applicationContext)
                            .location(getClass().getResource("/fxml/addUpdateCustomer.fxml"))
                            .load();
            Stage addUpdateCustomerModal = new Stage();
            addUpdateCustomerModal.initOwner(primaryStage);
            addUpdateCustomerModal.centerOnScreen();
            addUpdateCustomerModal.setScene(new Scene(loader));
            addUpdateCustomerModal.show();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CustomersController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @EventListener
    public void addCustomerEventListener(AddCustomerEvent addCustomerEvent){
        System.out.println("Heey");
        customerList.add(addCustomerEvent.getCustomer());
        customerList.add(new Customer(1, "Name 5", "Second 5", "005"));
    }
}
```

I also have created a small javafx app to reproduce the described problem in [this github repo](https://github.com/yunus89/javafx-spring.git)

## Procedure

1. Clone and run the app
2. Click `Add Customer` button.
3. Fill `first name`, `second name` and `phone`.
4. Click `Save` button.

You will notice the just added member is not in the table view

Comment: I don't understand the negative one, please give a reason.

Comment: You should create a minimal version (a [MCVE]) of your application and post it in the question, instead of linking to external code. If you remove the github repo, or it ceases to be available for any other reason, then your question would no longer be meaningful for other users. You should be able to reduce this to a few small files that can be posted here: you don't need the full machinery of the repo you forked in order to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I thought repo way is the best way, but okay, i will do what you tell me. And thanks for your clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that we use different instance of the controller, because this is a `scope="prototype"`. We need it for 2 different things:

- 1 is injected when the FXML is loaded as a controller
- 1 other is created for listening to the queue.

A solution would be to create a Singleton that is listening to the queue and store the customer list. Then include this singleton in the controller via @autowire.

Of course in this case, the bus is not really needed: You just can add this singleton in the AddCustomerController, and then add directly the element in the list.

Here is the solution for the singleton :

```
@Component
public class CustomersSingleton {

  private final ObservableList<Customer> customerList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

  @EventListener
  public void addCustomerEventListener(AddCustomerEvent addCustomerEvent){
      System.out.println("Heey");
      customerList.add(addCustomerEvent.getCustomer());
      customerList.add(new Customer(1, "Name 5", "Second 5", "005"));
  }

  public ObservableList<Customer> getCustomerList() {
    return customerList;
  }

}
```

then modify your controller

```
// remove attributes customerList and customerListProperty then modify method:

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@SuppressWarnings ({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    clmFirstName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
    clmSecondName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("secondName"));
    clmPhone.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("phone"));
    ObservableList<Customer> customerList = customersSingleton.getCustomerList();
    tblCustomers.setItems(customerList);
    addCustomer.setOnAction(this::addCustomerActionEvent);

    customerList.add(new Customer(1, "Name 1", "Second 1", "001"));
    customerList.add(new Customer(2, "Name 2", "Second 2", "002"));
    customerList.add(new Customer(1, "Name 3", "Second 3", "003"));
    customerList.add(new Customer(1, "Name 4", "Second 4", "004"));

}
```

Side note: The simplier but really discouraged solution to make it work is just to remove `@Scope("prototype")` annotation,  but you must not have a singleton as a Controller because the screen has many instance, and each screen need its controller

```
@Component
//@Scope("prototype")
public class CustomersController implements Initializable {
```

remark don't use this!

Comment: I added `Platform.runLater(Runnable)` the way you recommended but still it was not added

Comment: Plus, i checked size of `customerList` in the event listener method, both before adding customer and after is `0`(both outside `Platform.runLater(Runnable)`)  yet there is already `4` customers in tableview

Comment: But when i check size before and after adding new customer in `Platform.runLater(Runnable)` i get `0` for before and `2` for after

Comment: ok, that means that you have not the same instance of controller or list, the thread was not the main problem. I try to check .

Comment: @Yunus Einsteinium : I edited the answer, it is an instance problem as I suspected: You have 2 instances of your controller

Comment: What do you mean by "..., but in your case there is only one instance of the screen", do you mean the main stage? This application in repo is just an example, in the real app i have the a stage the load root layout. Now the root layout houses controllers dynamically if required by user

Comment: Exactly, the main stage in your repo: In other words, if you load more than 1 time "customers.fxml", the associated controller must not be a singleton,  I may add the right singleton usage in my Answar: create a new singleton class,; that contains the list and the listener, then inject it in CustomersController

Comment: Ofcourse there will be many UIs to be displayed, and one might choose another Ui and afterwards load customers UI again. If i make customers UI controller singleton, next time i load it will still be in state i left it

Comment: Ok, then i updated again the answer with a valid Spring singleton.